# use an output test case (xml) in another test case like input value, RIDE/robot framework

Tags: testing, automation, robotframework, testcase

I have a  problem to automate my test cases, so my problem is that I need to use an output test case value in the next test case like an input...
I can't found the solution, did anyone have an idea??

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single value the you can set the value using 'Set Suite Variable' or 'Set global variable' and use the same value directly in the another test.
                            (OR)
If the result is coming in xml format, use the XML Library and read the values.
example program

As you have mentioned your output looks like `<clientID>13044512</clientId>` i am creating the xml file like below: (added  tag because with only  it will not work, it need some root tag, let me know,whether anythign comes or not, if not i will explain how to add that root tag)

```
output.xml
<clientID>13044512</clientID>


*** Settings ***
Library           XML
Library           OperatingSystem
*** variables ***
${xmlFile}=      \path\to\xmlfile\output.xml

*** Test cases ***
Access xml tag text
     # Get the xml file contents
     ${file}=    Get File    ${xmlFile}

     #create file and update the old same file with root tag
     Create File    ${xmlFile}    <xml>${file}</xml>

     #parse xml to element tree structure and get root tag
     ${rootTag}=    Parse Xml    ${xmlFile}

     #from root tag find the following element text
      ${value}=    Get Element Text    ${rootTag}    clientID    normalize_whitespace=True
```

`${value}` will have `13044512` value.

If the xml file have other than  tag then in the place of `clientID` we need to specify the path of the element from root tag.

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: the problem is not to set suite variable or global variable , the problem is how to get the element from the output ( the output is an xml file) and how it will be known in robot framework.  this is the real problem.

Comment: read that xml in another testcase and use, robot framework has [XML](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html) library to work on xml, updated the answer with xml example

Comment: can you explain what is ${elementXpath} ? it can't be resolved with robot framework

Comment: updated the answer based on your xml, please check, if other than <clientID> no other tags will be there in the xml, then we need to add 'root tag', answer has steps including how to add root tag, if not required then use the code from third line. please make sure next time onward provide complete details in the question, it will save your time and the person who helps you, thanks

Comment: Thanks but i  need to specify the path of the element because i have a large xml output. do you have an idea ?

Comment: except root node, give complete path till your element. please delete your answers  for this question, those are your comments not answers, please do that way next time onward; if possible give me the sample xml file

Answer (score 1):

The [Robot Framework guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html) has a specific section on [variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables) and the [scope of variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-set-test-suite-global-variable-keywords). In these sections you will find the keywords that you can use. If you `Set Suite Variable` if the variable value shouldn't go beyond the suite (i.e. file). If you want the value to stay beyond that point to, then use `Set Global Variable`.